# Trouble with d3.js: How can I assign values to predefined scales and accurately show -ve values on -ve, the +ve side and neutral values on both sides?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I tried to assign values to pre-defined Scale +ve, -ve or neutral like good, bad or neutral. Values are successfully assigned but show in just one way, can you guide me to to show it right way in d3.js
below is html and script.js file data. Assigning values to predefined scales in d3.js, how can I show -ve values on the +ve side and neutral values on both sides

Trouble with d3.js: How can I assign values to predefined scales and accurately show -ve values on the +ve side and neutral values on both sides?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Survey Data Visualization</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="script2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

# Here is script.js code

const data = [
  { category: "Question 1", value: 75, value1: 65, value2: 55 },
  { category: "Question 2", value: 62, value1: 52, value2: 42 },
];

const AnswerScale = [
  { value: "bad" },
  { value1: "neutral" },
  { value2: "good" },
];

// Set up chart dimensions
const margin = { top: 50, right: 150, bottom: 50, left: 150 };
const width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Create SVG element
const svg = d3
  .select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Set x-axis scale
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-100, 100]).range([0, width]);

// Set y-axis scale
const yScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map((d) => d.category))
  .range([0, height])
  .padding(0.1);

// Set color scale for different values
const colorScale = d3
  .scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(Object.keys(data[0]))
  .range(["green", "red", "yellow"]);

// Create stacked bar chart
svg
  .selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .join("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(0, ${yScale(d.category)})`)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data((d) => Object.entries(d).slice(1))
  .join("rect")
  .attr("x", (d) => xScale(Math.min(0, d[1])))
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", (d) => Math.abs(xScale(d[1]) - xScale(0)))
  .each(function (d){
    console.log("ddddd", d)
    if (!"bad"){
      return (d) => xScale(d[1]) * -1;
    } else if (!"neutral") {
      return (d) => xScale(d[2]) + (xScale(d[0]) - xScale(d[2])) / 2;
    } else if (!"good") {
      return (d) => xScale(d[3]);
    }
  })
  .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
  .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d[0]));

// Add x-axis
svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(20));

// Add y-axis
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

// Add legend
const legend = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width +20}, 0)`);

const legendData = AnswerScale.map((d) => Object.values(d)[0]);

legend
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(legendData)
  .join("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 20)
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(`value${i}`));

legend
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(legendData)
  .join("text")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 20 + 12.5)
  .text((d) => d);
```